# Why is PDFBox overwriting multiple Fields, even when they don't match the fullyQualifiedName? (Kotlin Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, pdfbox

I'm using com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.1  version of PDFBox.

I have the following code.

```
 val skillList = listOf<String>("Athletics","Acrobatics","Sleight of Hand", "Stealth","Acrana", "History","Investigation","Nature", "Religion", "Animal Handling", "Insight", "Medicine", "Perception", "Survival", "Deception", "Intimidation", "Performance", "Persuasion"


private fun getField(acroForm:PDAcroForm,name:String): PDTextField {
    return acroForm.getField(name) as PDTextField
}
var temp = 0

        skillList.forEach {
            val field = getField(acroForm,it.name)
            temp += 1
             field.value = temp.toString()

        }
```

Here is a link to the PDF.
[PDF in question](http://www.kylevp.com/csOnePage.pdf)
My problem is that my final PDF (all fields with unique names that match the above list), has many of them being set with the 17th out of 18 passes.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does Kotlin return if the field doesn't match? What do you get when you trace the name of the field you get? I don't know Kotlin, but I think I've read somewhere that it doesn't have null values.

Comment: I have more complex code that searches for a matching field, and cancels if it can't find one.   Saying Kotlin doesn't have nulls, is not entirely accurate.   But in this case,  the program crashes if there is no matching field. 

I've boiled the code down to the simplest version to highlight the problem I'm having.   If I had a variable without a matching field, it would crash this version of the app. (just tested to be sure.  It does)

Comment: Unfortunately you don't share the pdf in question. I would assume that the fields are arranged in a hierarchy, e.g. `text.field.1`, `text.field.2`, ... and you set the value of `text`. That would make pdfbox recursively set all fields starting with "text".

Comment: I've added a link above to the PDF in question,  I don't *think* I have them arranged in a hierarchy, but I'm new to PDF and could easily be mistaken.

Comment: Forgot to mention the people I was replying to in the above comments.  @mkl

Comment: Also forgot to tag @TilmanHausherr in my reply above.

Comment: get the field name with getPartialName(), and the full name with getFullyQualifiedName().

Comment: The situation is even weirder. Just click into those newly filled-in fields in Adobe Reader (desktop version). The number in edit view is the number you'd expect...

Comment: As an aside, one field name is spelled incorrectly, you use "Acrana" instead of "Arcana".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in PDFBox (1.8.x and 2.x) when filling PDF forms which only occurs if in the original form multiple fields share the same XObject as appearance stream.

#### In detail

Your original document contains many empty text fields. Several subsets of them share the same appearance stream, e.g. "Athletics" and "Religion":

[image: Athletics][image: Religion]

As you can see they both share the XObject in PDF object 479.

When PDFBox fills in the form values, it first sets the value of "Athletics" to "1" and also updates the appearance XObject to show "1", and later it sets the value of "Religion" to "9" and updates the appearance XObject to show "9". The end result: In a viewer both "Athletics" and "Religion" show "9" as value.

The issue is that PDFBox assumes it can simply *update* an existing appearance stream when setting the value of a form field. Actually it must *replace* it, probably also the **AP** dictionary if it happens to be indirect as it might also be shared.

#### A work-around

A work-around in your case is to drop the existing empty appearances before setting the field:

```
field.getDictionary().removeItem(COSName.AP)
field.value = temp.toString()
```

(Probably that line can be shortened in Kotlin to `field.dictionary.removeItem(COSName.AP)` but I know next to nothing about Kotlin...)

#### Backgrounds

One might wonder whether a construction as found in the source PDF here (i.e. appearance streams shared by multiple text fields) is valid at all. But indeed I could not find anything forbidding this in the PDF specification, on the contrary the following section about annotations in general (form field widgets are special annotations) can be taken to explicitly allow it:

> A given annotation dictionary shall be referenced from the **Annots** array of only one page. This requirement applies only to the annotation dictionary itself, not to subsidiary objects, which may be shared among multiple annotations.

*(both ISO 32000-1 and ISO 32000-2, section 12.5.2 "Annotation Dictionaries")*

Comment: I've accepted  the answer because you've 100% identified the problem.   Kotlin itself isn't playing nice with the work around though.   

 field.dictionary().removeItem(COSName.AP) 

throws an error that it is protected.  At least from here I have a direction to go though!  Thanks for your help?   is it possible to change the appearance stream in the PDF for fields?

Comment: There is both a public method `getDictionary()` and a private member `dictionary`. So, have you tried with `field.getDictionary()`? Or use `field.getCOSObject()` and cast it to `COSDictionary`.

Comment: I did, but kotlin doesn't recognize getDictionary.... which is super weird.

Comment: I should clarify, I tried using getDictionary(),   but I'm not following your idea to use getCOSObject().

Comment: Both methods `getDictionary()` and `getCOSObject()` return the same object, merely the former one is types `COSDictionary` while the latter one is typed `COSBase` and must still be cast to `COSDictionary`.

Comment: That explains it!   Kotlin infers what to cast, and is not typed.   That's why getDictionary wasn't working.   COSBase works without specifying what to cast.   Typing the Java version of COSBase incidentally, will auto fix that when pasted into android studio.

You've been a tremendous help.  Best person I've ever met on stack.

Comment: Thanks, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4471 created. I'm undecided if this is a bug or not. Having the /AP/N objects for different fields seems weird to me.

Comment: *"I'm undecided if this is a bug or not. Having the /AP/N objects for different fields seems weird to me."* - I wasn't sure either, so i looked into the spec. I found nothing to forbid this, so the quoted section appears to allow it. And I've actually seen weirder cases of object re-use.

Comment: @mkl what is the application name that you used to see the detailed view for fields presented in the image?

Comment: In the case above I used iText RUPS. Similarly you can use PDFBox PDFDebugger.